# Get the Angular multi application name

Tags: angular6, angular7

My angular.json file looks like this:

```
projects: {
   "app-1" {
  ...
},
   "app-2" {
  ...
},
}
```

How can the app names (app-1 or app-2) to be used as a variable in the application?

ng serve --project="app-1"

Answer (score -1):

If you have a project with multiple applications, use angular upgrade guide (https://update.angular.io/) instructions to upgrade your application. One of the step while performing upgrade is to run

ng upgrade @angular/cli
(once you upgrade your @angular/cli to v6+). This will generate new angular.json file using your existing angular-cli.json file for multiple applciations.

Upgrade Angular CLI

OR
Manually edit your angular.json to add new application to the existing project. Editing JSON file for Another Application.

ng serve --project="second-app"

ng build --prod --project="second-app" // build prod app

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how can I use "second-app" as a variable inside the application?